# Puppet: Could not evaluate: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File

Tags: puppet, facter

I got an error when installing puppet on my server and executing command `sudo puppet resource group puppet ensure=present`

The error message is

```
[solr@e3slri01 ~]$ sudo puppet resource group puppet ensure=present
Failed to load feature test for libuser: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File
Error: /File[/etc/puppet]: Could not evaluate: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet]: Could not evaluate: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File
Notice: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Dependency File[/var/lib/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/var/lib/puppet/run]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Dependency File[/var/lib/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/var/lib/puppet/state]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Dependency File[/var/lib/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Dependency File[/var/lib/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/var/lib/puppet/log]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Notice: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Dependency File[/etc/puppet] has failures: true
Warning: /File[/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: Could not run: Got 2 failure(s) while initializing: Could not evaluate: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File; Could not evaluate: uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File
```

I am newbie to puppet and know nothing about ruby. I don't know what I do wrong here.

Can you tell me how to fix this? thanks.

BTW.

```
[solr@e3slri01 ~]$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [x86_64-linux]
[solr@e3slri01 ~]$ sudo puppet --version
3.3.2
[solr@e3slri01 ~]$ sudo facter --version
1.7.3
```

And PS.

```
[solr@e3slri01 puppet]$ pwd
/etc/puppet
[solr@e3slri01 puppet]$ ll
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4133 Feb 25 22:56 auth.conf
```

It seems that some files and folders are missed in `/etc/puppet`.

Comment: Tried running in Vagrant to see if your config is correct or is it merely that installing puppet on your node does not work?

Comment: I got this error when updating from Puppet 3.4 to 3.5. Googling for ["uninitialized constant Puppet::FileSystem::File"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Failed+to+load+feature+test+for+libuser%3A+uninitialized+constant+Puppet%3A%3AFileSystem%3A%3AFile%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#channel=fflb&q=%22uninitialized+constant+Puppet%3A%3AFileSystem%3A%3AFile%22&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=active) shows a few other people with this error after an upgrade. See the puppet bugs PUP-2345 & PUP-1603 .

Answer (score 0):

For me, this happenend where I had a version of puppet installed via gem, and also via Ubuntu packages (from the puppet labs repo). 
Doing "gem uninstall puppet" and then "apt-get install puppet" fixed it for me.